# JCE is missing the toolbar on Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, toolbar, joomla-content-editor

I don't know what happened, but JCE's toolbar is hidden. How can I enable/show it again?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I downloaded the JCE plugin, installed It, enabled, but I still don't see the editor's toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JCE is enabled and selected as the default editor then go to Site > User Manager and edit the user you are logging in as.  Select JCE as the editor for that user.
It is actually recommended for security reasons to use "No editor" for the default option in Global Setup and override it on the user level to JCE.

Answer (score 0):

To enable it go to plugins check whether JCE plugin is enable or not if it is not please enable it and check.

If still Editor did not display then go to global configuration-> select JCE in default

Comment: Thank you for answer. JCE is enabled, in Global Configuration I selected JCE in default, but still the same.